# How to make HttpURLConnection get header from servlet response?

Tags: java, servlets

Servlet code:

```
if (errorMessage!=null) {
   response.setHeader("errorMessage",errorMessage);
   response.setStatus(200);
 } else {
   response.setStatus(500);
 }
```

Client Code:

```
HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
if (httpCon.getResponseCode==200 && httpCon.getHeaderField("errorMessage")!=null) {
   out.println("Error: "+ httpCon.getHeaderField("errorMessage"));
 } else {
     out.println("Error 500");
 }
```

The problem is that

```
httpCon.getHeaderField("errorMessage")
```

is always coming as null though errorMessage is not always null.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you provide more code on your `errorMessage` variable and the `url` connection?

Comment: did you examine the http traffic to ensure that the header is being propagated?

Comment: What else is happening in your servlet code?

Comment: maybe the servlet response was already committed

Comment: Hi. Could you check if the heaser is present on the servlet after "setting it"? u can use the method: containsHeader(java.lang.String) for this. On the other hand you can try with the addHeader(java.lang.String, java.lang.String) method. If i understand the api (HttpServletResponse api) correctly, before setting a header, you should add it. But just for triying... Not sure :)

Comment: @Oldskultxo You don't have to add a header before you set it, and the question isn't about `HttpServletResponse`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `getResponseMessage()`.

But 200 means *no* error. It means OK. Why are you expecting an error message?